# Tiny error in the ChartJs book

Tags: chart.js, gitbook

If you link to a ChartJs topic and happen to append space %20 after the url it is included in the web display and indents the table of information.

[Link to ChartJs *pointhitradius*](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html?h=pointhitradius%20)

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

It's matching on the space between the words (you can go to http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html?h=pointhitradius%20Number as well to match across words), and inserting a `mark` element when it finds a match (in this case, to the space). Inserting an element between table cells results in this kind of behavior, but the highlighting library is built for more generic uses.

The particular library they're using for highlighting looks to be https://markjs.io.